# Set manual location of legend with matplotlib and GetDistTool

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, legend

I try to set manually the location for the main legend of a main plot produced by  [Getdist tool](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The plot below represents the 1/2 sigma confidence levels coming from a covariance matrix with joint distributions. It is produced by  [Getdist tool](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[image: issue with legend]

[Getdist tool](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tool allows to specify the location of legends : I tried with `legend_loc = 'upper right'` but as you can see, there is an overlapping at the top of figure. I want to shift on the right the legend to avoid this overlapping : is it possible ? if yes, how to ?

The main routine that generates this plot is :

```
g.triangle_plot([matrix1, matrix2],
                  names,
                  filled = True,
                 legend_labels = ['Opt. Flat. No Gamma. - optimistic case - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into accound a = 200', 'Pess. Flat. No Gamma. - pessimistic case - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into account a = 300' ],
                  legend_loc = 'upper right',
                  contour_colors = ['darkblue','red'],
                  line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'},
                  {'lw':2, 'color':'red'}]
                  )
```

### Update 1

I can't manage to apply shifts on the lower left corner on the legend by doing :

```
g.triangle_plot([matrix1, matrix2],
                names,
                filled = True,               
                 legend_labels = ['Opt. Flat. No Gamma. - optimistic case - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into accound a = 200', 'Pess. Flat. No Gamma. - pessimistic case - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into account a = 300' ],
                legend_loc = 'center right',
                contour_colors = ['darkblue','red'],
                line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'},
                {'lw':2, 'color':'red'}],                
                bbox_to_anchor = [0.1, 0.5]
                )
```

As you can see, I tried to  put legend at 0.1 from the top and in the middle.

But unfortunately, this doesn't change anything, I get with these parameters the following plot:

[image: offsets not applied]

You can remark that with these parameters, a simple shift to the top would be enough but for instant, I don't know how to perform this.

I have also tried to remove `loc` and  `bbox_to_anchor` from `g.triangle_plot` and attempt to do directly :

```
g.fig.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=[0.1, 0.1])
```

But same issues of offset not applied in the final figure.

Comment: Helpful remark: in English, one says "I hope the problem is clear", not "I hope the problematic is clear". However, on Stack Overflow we are keen to trim chatty problem - stating that you hope something is clear does not help with its clarity, so it is expected that you refrain from making these sorts of redundant remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an argument in pyplot's `legend` function called `bbox_to_anchor`. It's something like a relative deviation and I'm not exactly sure how it works. But basically you can set there some values of horizontal and vertical shifts and then adjust to fit your desired position.

For example you can write
`plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[2.32, 0.5], loc='center right')`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I tried to change the values for `bbox_to_anchor` but this doesn't produce any changing in the location of the legend.

Comment: Hm, it's strange because that's how I usually adjust the location of a legend. Maybe it doesn't work with GetDist, I tried to use only in pyplot.

Comment: Indeed, it's stange. I think this is due maybe to the fact that main routine 'g.triangle_plot` , that generates the plot, uses its own parameter `legend_loc` parameter. I must add that I have defined `g`by : `g = plots.get_subplot_plotter()`. What do you think about it ?

Comment: I took a look into their code on github and it looks like they use the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter (https://github.com/cmbant/getdist/blob/master/getdist/plots.py#L1872). And I also ran some code from here https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot_gallery.html, pasted there the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter in the `g.add_legend` and it changed the position of legend entirely. So maybe you should call the `g.add_legend` function directly. Also try to send `bbox_to_anchor` with some higher parameters like [2.1, 2.5]. Maybe for small differences in position it's not as noticeable.

Comment: Your solution with `g.add_legend` works but now, I am faced to another issue : the routine `g.trianglr_plot` adds another legend even if I have removed `legend_loc`, `bbox_to_anchor` and majority of stuff related to the legend in this routine.

Comment: Oh, I don't know then, it looks strange. I think it deserves an issue on Github.